# Remove "0" value results from QUERY

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

This is the data set

[image]

This is the formula I am using to query.

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE A <> '' GROUP BY A")
```

I want the end results to remove the asset if the sum amount is =< 0.

i.e. ABC would not show in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a new condition where SUM(B) is >0

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE A <> '' AND SUM(B) >0 GROUP BY A")
```

### UPDATE

Sorry, then you'll need to wrap it in another QUERY:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE A <> '' GROUP BY A"),"WHERE Col2 >0")
```

Try it and let me know

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: CANNOT_BE_IN_WHERE: SUM(`B`)